# Inside an Object.value loop how can I get the key

Tags: javascript

I have to create match condition based on an array my array will look like below

```
var groupData={
  A:[
      {rollnum: 1, name:'Arya',    age:15}, 
      {rollnum: 2, name:'Aryan',   age:15}
    ],
  B:[
      {rollnum:11, name:'Biba',    age:15},
      {rollnum:12, name:'Bimisha', age:15}
  ]
}
```

I am looping using for loop. How can reduce the loops. Can any one suggest me a proper way for this

```
Object.values(groupData).flat().forEach((rowitem)=>{
  query={};
  Object.keys(rowitem).forEach(eachField=>{
    query[eachField]["$in"].push(rowitem[eachField])
  });
  fullarray[Object.keys(groupData)]=matchQuery;  
})
```

I need an output (fullarray) like below

```
{
  'A':{
    rollnum:{'$in':[1,2]},
    name:   {'$in':['Arya', 'Aryan']},
    age:    {'$in':[15]}
  },
  'B':{
    rollnum:{'$in':[11,12]},
    name:   {'$in':['Biba', 'Bimisha']},
    age:    {'$in':[15]}
  }   
}
```

Here 'A' 'B' is not coming correctly

Comment: What's the point of all the `$in` keys?

Comment: `$in` makes me think this is `mongodb` related. @user1187 If this is mongodb related you should include that as a tag for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Object.values()` since that discards the `A` and `B` keys.

Use nested loops, one loop for the properties in the object, and a nested loop for the arrays.

You need to create the nested objects and arrays before you can add to them.

```js
var groupData = { A:
   [ { rollnum: 1,
       name: 'Arya',
       age:15}, 
      { rollnum: 2,
       name: 'Aryan',
       age:15}, ],
  B:
   [ { rollnum: 11,
       name: 'Biba',
       age:15},
     { rollnum: 12,
       name: 'Bimisha',
       age:15}  ] }

result = {};
Object.entries(groupData).forEach(([key, arr]) => {
  if (!result[key]) {
    result[key] = {};
  }
  cur = result[key];
  arr.forEach(obj => {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key2, val]) => {
      if (!cur[key2]) {
        cur[key2] = {
          "$in": []
        };
      }
      cur[key2]["$in"].push(val);
    });
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Will the execution of this code takes more. I tried like this using for loop